# Where is the Add Size Class Customization in Xcode 7.2?

Tags: ios, xcode7, size-classes

As I'm using Size Classes, I need to implement my view's property for different sizes.

Apple, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/ChangeViewPosition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH9-SW1), says this function is in Xcode's Attribute inspector

[image]

[image]

But I don't find it in Xcode 7.2 (7C68) ! Where is it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following screen shots

[image: Select your **view** to set the add class customisation] in screen shot I selected `UITextView`
Then select the left how **document line icon** refer

[image: document line]

Select any of your **constraint** for customisation

[image: click here]

After selection check the **Utilities**  in right side.

[image: check here]

Then click on **+** icon beside the **installed check box**

Then you will see the below screen

[image]

Solution 2: 
Check the view section in attribute inspector.

[image: Check here]

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. I had to select a property (Label, Button, etc...) first.

[image]